# Text highlighting not showing up in Firefox on Linux

Tags: firefox

I recently upgraded Firefox and discovered that highlighted text was no longer showing up! Text would still be highlighted (I can copy / paste to verify), but both in edit controls and on the page itself, highlighting just wasn't working. Every other application worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to go to about:config and add the following string values:

```
ui.textHighlightBackground : #c0c0c0
ui.textHighlightForeground : #000
ui.textSelectBackground    : #c0c0c0
ui.textSelectForeground    : #000
```

You can, of course, customize these colors to your liking. #c0c0c0 is a nice neutral gray, while #000 is of course straight black.